# Set height's of element on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dashboard type page on the left i have tabs & right i have content of the respective tab. I am using bootstrap so i made 2 columns 1 for tab & other for it's contents but my problem is that the border of tabs is not covering the entire height of the content i want it to cover the full height so i have written a jquery that will set the height of the last tab ("#ws") but that work only on page load not on button click.

TLDR

1) Go to http://kwebmakerusa.com/whp/v3/dashboard.html

2) Can you see the border-right of the tab it's height is same as the content on the right

3) click any other tab eg:address book. Notice the height shrinks

What i am trying to do is keep the height same as the content on the right

here is my html :

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 hidden-xs nopadding">
    <div id="dtnavs">
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt active" id="dasht">My Dashboard</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="cartt">My Cart</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="addresst">Address Book</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="ordert">My Orders</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="wisht">My Wishlist</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="newst">Newsletters</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tabtxt" id="ws"></div><!--set height dynamicaly-->
  </div>
```

On click

```
  $("#addresst,#mtab3").click(function() {
    $('#dashboardtab,#carttab,#ordertab,#wishtab,#newslettertab,#video').slideUp(500);
    $('#addtab').slideDown(500);
    $(".dashnav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");    
    setwsheight("#addtab");
    $(".ccatname,#bcactive").text("Address Book");
    console.log(this);
    return false;
});
```

setwsheight();

```
function setwsheight(sh){
    $('#ws').delay(1000).height($(sh).height()-$('#dtnavs').height());
    var str = "$('#ws').height($("+sh+").height()-$('#dtnavs').height())";
    console.log(str);
    console.log(sh+" height : "+$(sh).height());
    console.log("dtnavs height : "+$('#dtnavs').height());
    console.log("WS height :" +$('#ws').height());
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without jquery
I have change some Your HTML Code Like

Remove this class in content tab `left40`

Apply this css your content side parent content like `col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 nopadding`

```
.selector {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

apply this css tab content  `col-md-2 col-sm-3 hidden-xs nopadding`

```
.selector{
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var newHeight=your calculation;
$('#ws').animate({
   height:newHeight+"your unit"
},yourDelay,function(){});
```

Also if that still doesn't work, try making the `#ws` element's position property absolute in a CSS file, along with the code posted in this answer.